# summing element of a row matrix to another matrix with their corresponding columns

Tags: r, matrix

I want to sum each row of matrix A with matrix B. A reproducible example with expected result:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(round(runif(15, 1, 15)), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
B <- matrix(seq(100,500,100), nrow = 1, ncol = 5)

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5   14   14    2   11
[2,]    6    4   10    4    6
[3,]    9   14   10    3   12

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  100  200  300  400  500

# Expected result
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  105  214  314  402  511
[2,]  106  204  310  404  506
[3,]  109  214  310  403  512
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sweep` to add `A` and `B`.

```
sweep(A, 2, B, "+")
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  105  214  314  402  511
#[2,]  106  204  310  404  506
#[3,]  109  214  310  403  512
```

You can also use `col`:

```
A + B[col(A)]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  105  214  314  402  511
#[2,]  106  204  310  404  506
#[3,]  109  214  310  403  512
```